# Null Value for REQUEST_URI from Apache Web Server

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

My goal is to obtain the original request URL before proxying to another URL.  I'm using Apache Http Server 2.4 in conjunction with Jetty.  I'm creating a custom header called X-Forwarded-Uri in my httpd.conf file that provides me with the original request URI.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ...

   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Uri %{REQUEST_URI}e

   ProxyPass /foo http://localhost:8080/foo
   ProxyPassReverse /foo http://localhost:8080/foo

   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I make a request for http://localhost/foo and try to retrieve the value of X-Forwarded-Uri from my server side code, I consistently get back `null`. The request URI is supposed to be the path that comes after the host name and port number.  Since I'm supplying `/foo`, I would expect to get back `/foo`.

Do I have a configuration error?

Answer (score 1):

%{REQUEST_URI}e is not available to the internal var lookup stuff in mod_headers, since it is not always set, and when it is, it is set too late in request processing.

Use the expr="%{REQUEST_URI}" flavor of expressions instead.  It knows how to answer that w/o the dependency on the environment variable by the same name.